# How can i get Authentication with Firebase to work with Angular2 FINAL?

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

So, I, too, upgraded to Angular2 Final. I did the migration project steps to move everything over. I'm getting zero errors, it authenticates. However, the problem happens after authentication. When it redirects back to the page, it's not getting that delicious authentication data. It acts like I'm not logged in. This is happening locally, and on firebase hosting. I double checked that I'm not blocking cookies. I stripped down the authentication options to just facebook. It just doesn't work. It was ok prior to going to final. The last version I was on was RC5.

I'm using Typescript 2.0.2.

My app.module looks like this:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule, ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CollapseDirective, DropdownDirective, DropdownToggleDirective, DropdownMenuDirective} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import {
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
    defaultFirebase,
    AngularFire,
    AuthMethods,
    AuthProviders,
    firebaseAuthConfig, AngularFireModule
} from 'angularfire2';
import {RoomlyNavbarComponent} from './shared/roomly-navbar/roomly-navbar.component';
import {RoomlyRoomsComponent} from './roomly-rooms/roomly-rooms.component';
import {RoomlyHomeComponent} from './roomly-home/roomly-home.component';
import {
    routing,
    appRoutingProviders
} from './app.routes';
import {RoomlyRoomComponent} from './roomly-room/roomly-room.component';
import {RoomlyPhotoUploaderComponent} from './roomly-photo-uploader/roomly-photo-uploader.component';
import {RoomlyItemComponent} from './roomly-item/roomly-item.component';
import {RoomlyBuildingComponent} from './roomly-building/roomly-building.component';
import {RoomlyBuildingsComponent} from './roomly-buildings/roomly-buildings.component';
import {BuildingFormComponent} from './building-form/building-form.component';

const myFirebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "REMOVED",
    authDomain: "REMOVED",
    databaseURL: "REMOVED",
    storageBucket: "REMOVED",
};

const myFirebaseAuthConfig = {
    provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
    method: AuthMethods.Redirect
};

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CollapseDirective,
        DropdownDirective,
        DropdownToggleDirective,
        DropdownMenuDirective,
        RoomlyNavbarComponent,
        RoomlyRoomsComponent,
        RoomlyRoomComponent,
        RoomlyHomeComponent,
        RoomlyPhotoUploaderComponent,
        RoomlyItemComponent,
        RoomlyBuildingComponent,
        RoomlyBuildingsComponent,
        BuildingFormComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        routing,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(myFirebaseConfig, myFirebaseAuthConfig)
    ],
    providers: [appRoutingProviders],
    entryComponents: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent,
        RoomlyNavbarComponent
        ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

My app.component looks like this. I'm using routes, so it's pretty bare. It just loads a page that contains the `router-outlet` and the navbar:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
  }
}
```

Finally, the home page where the actual logging in takes places looks like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods} from 'angularfire2';
import {AuthUser} from '../shared/AuthUser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-roomly-home',
    templateUrl: 'roomly-home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['roomly-home.component.css']
})
export class RoomlyHomeComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    user = {};
    authUser: AuthUser = new AuthUser('', '');
    loggedin: boolean;

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
        this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => console.log('hello ', auth));
        this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
            if (user) {
                // user logged in
                this.user = user;
                this.loggedin = true;
            }
            else {
                // user not logged in
                this.user = {};
                this.loggedin = false;
            }
        });
    }

    login() {
        this.af.auth.login();
    }

    loginFacebook() {
        this.af.auth.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup
        });
    }

    loginGoogle() {
        this.af.auth.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Google,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup
        });
    }

    loginTwitter() {
        this.af.auth.login({
            provider: AuthProviders.Twitter,
            method: AuthMethods.Popup
        });
    }

    logout() {
        this.af.auth.logout();
    }


}
```

I'm not sure what changed between RC5 and Final to cause it to fail. If it helps, here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Roomly Home Inventory",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.4.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Has anyone else run across this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, fixed it. There's two steps.

1. upgrade to `angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.5-preview`
2. `npm install @types/request@0.0.30`
3. Profit.

That solved the issue and everything works now. :)

Comment: Don't you just love it when you fix your own problems. :)